# Object is of type 'unknown' from Redux in Typescript

Tags: typescript

So, I'm using Typescript and Redux Toolkit in one Next project, I have added a type to the useSelector that comes from the library and the problem is fixed with that, but when I access the object I get this error `Object is of type 'unknown'`.

Here is how I define to use the state: `const cart = useSelector<CartT>(state => state.cart)`

And here is the type:

```
export type CartT = {
    state: any,
    cart: any
}
```

And here is how I access it: `<h1 style={{ fontSize: '2em' }}>$ {cart.cartTotal}</h1>`

This is my store:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import themeSlice from '../../@redux/themeSlice';
import couponsSlice from '../../@redux/couponsSlice';
import cartSlice from '../../@redux/cartSlice';
import userSlice from '../../@redux/userSlice';

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  theme: themeSlice,
  coupons: couponsSlice,
  cart: cartSlice,
  user: userSlice
});

export const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: combinedReducer,
  });

export const Reduxium = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true });
```

Comment: CartT or Cart<T>?

Comment: What do you mean, i just named it like that

Comment: this is the error: `Object is of type 'unknown'.`

Comment: in html there is a typo, there shouldn´t be any spaces between $ and {

Answer (score 1):

```
const cart = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.cart)
```

where `RootState` in your store.ts is:

```
import { combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createWrapper } from 'next-redux-wrapper';
import themeSlice from '../../@redux/themeSlice';
import couponsSlice from '../../@redux/couponsSlice';
import cartSlice from '../../@redux/cartSlice';
import userSlice from '../../@redux/userSlice';

const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  theme: themeSlice,
  coupons: couponsSlice,
  cart: cartSlice,
  user: userSlice
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;

export const makeStore = () =>
  configureStore({
    reducer: combinedReducer,
  });

export const Reduxium = createWrapper(makeStore, { debug: true });
```

For further info: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type

Comment: I did an update, can you customize the code based in my store is kinda different because I'm using next

Comment: you should add this type in your store `export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;` and then use it in your useSelector

Comment: can you make full edit of my redux store